# First Person Camera movement issues

Tags: c++, opengl, camera

I'm implementing a first person camera using the GLM library that provides me with some useful functions that calculate perspective and 'lookAt' matrices. I'm also using OpenGL but that shouldn't make a difference in this code.

Basically, what I'm experiencing is that I can look around, much like in a regular FPS, and move around. But the movement is constrained to the three axes in a way that if I rotate the camera, I would still move in the same direction as if I had not rotated it... Let me illustrate (in 2D, to simplify things).[image]

In this image, you can see four camera positions.
Those marked with a one are before movement, those marked with a two are after movement.
The red triangles represent a camera that is oriented straight forward along the z axis. The blue triangles represent a camera that hasbeen rotated to look backward along the x axis (to the left).
When I press the 'forward movement key', the camera moves forward along the z axis in both cases, disregarding the camera orientation.

What I want is a more FPS-like behaviour, where pressing forward moves me in the direction the camera is facing. I thought that with the arguments I pass to `glm::lookAt`, this would be achieved. Apparently not.

What is wrong with my calculations?

```
// Calculate the camera's orientation
float angleHori = -mMouseSpeed * Mouse::x; // Note that (0, 0) is the center of the screen
float angleVert = -mMouseSpeed * Mouse::y;

glm::vec3 dir(
    cos(angleVert) * sin(angleHori),
    sin(angleVert),
    cos(angleVert) * cos(angleHori)
);

glm::vec3 right(
    sin(angleHori - M_PI / 2.0f),
    0.0f,
    cos(angleHori - M_PI / 2.0f)
);

glm::vec3 up = glm::cross(right, dir);

// Calculate projection and view matrix
glm::mat4 projMatrix = glm::perspective(mFOV, mViewPortSizeX / (float)mViewPortSizeY, mZNear, mZFar);
glm::mat4 viewMatrix = glm::lookAt(mPosition, mPosition + dir, up);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually in another method. When moving the camera, I needed to do this:

```
void Camera::moveX(char s)
{
    mPosition += s * mSpeed * mRight;
}

void Camera::moveY(char s)
{
    mPosition += s * mSpeed * mUp;
}

void Camera::moveZ(chars)
{
    mPosition += s * mSpeed * mDirection;
}
```

To make the camera move across the correct axes.

Answer (score 1):

`gluLookAt` takes 3 parameters: eye, centre and up. The first two are positions while the last is a vector. If you're planning on using this function it's better that you maintain only these three parameters consistently.

Coming to the issue with the calculation. I see that the `position` variable is unchanged throughout the code. All that changes is the look at point I.e. `centre` only. The right thing to do is to first do `position +=  dir`, which will move the camera (position) along the direction pointed to by `dir`. Now to update the `centre`, the second parameter can be left as-is: `position + dir`; this will work since the position was already updated to the new position and from there we've a point farther in `dir` direction to look at.

Comment: Wouldn't doing `position += dir` just move the camera by itself, because `dir` is always different from **0**? (I just checked, this just makes it move by itself indeed).

Comment: What you do mean by itself? I presume you need a movement in the direction where the camera is looking at (forward or backward based on the key-pressed). In other words, it needs to move by its axes instead of following the world's axes.

Comment: I think I just got it, thanks. As soon as I get the chance, I'll try something out and report back!